# <NuxtLink /> not is not providing internal link like an anchor tag

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a link defined in nuxt pages like this:

```
<NuxtLink to="/#section-x">Section X</NuxtLink>
```

The link is actually added to the menu in my global layout file. When I try to click the link from a page different than a root page (/any-path) the link is taking me back to the landing page and displaying the section as expected. But when I try to click the link from the root page (/), it's not performing any navigation.

I tried using anchor tag in the same way:

```
<a href="/#section-x">Section X</NuxtLink>
```

The anchor tag will work fine for the root page internal navigation but when clicked from a different page, it will provide a navigation to the root page but not to the internal link(e.g. #section-x).

Is there any way to use the  or  tag and providing an internal html navigation too from any pages as it should?

Comment: what version of `nuxt` are you using?  Also, i believe the correct "tag" should be `<nuxt-link>`

Comment: Each vue component can be referenced both by pascal case(<NuxtLink />) and a camel case(<nuxt-link />). They both represent the same and it's not a new thing in vue/nuxt. :) As per my vue version is, it's v2.8.1.

Comment: @Vectrobyte i think you ment kebab-case  for the `nuxt-link` notation :P

Comment: Oops my bad, sorry. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/5359#issuecomment-475918374), installing [vue-scroll-to](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-scrollto) package

You could give this a shot

```
<nuxt-link
   :to="{path: '/', hash: 'section-x'}" 
   v-scroll-to="{el: '#section-x'}
">
  Section X
</nuxt-link>
```

I don't know how to Do it without adding more dependencies but I hope it helps